# Variant of cryptography

Tags: digital-communications

Let
$$S_1=\{(s_1(t),s_2(t)),(s_3(t),s_4(t))\}$$
and $$S_2=\{(s'_1(t),s'_2(t)),(s'_3(t),s'_4(t))\},$$

with $s_i(t)$ different waveforms.

We have $s_1(t)$ is orthogonal to $s_3(t)$ and $s_2(t)$ is orthogonal to $s_4(t)$. The pair $(s_1(t),s_2(t))$ corresponds to bit $0$ and the pair $(s_3(t),s_4(t))$ corresponds to bit $1$. To exchange a cryptographic key composed of bits $0$ and $1$, we use the set $S_1$. On reception the key is found using the set $S_1$ and $S_2$. The receiver knows the $2$ sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ while the transmitter knows just $S_1$. The cryptographic key is found by matched filtering to the reception.

Can this method be interesting to exchange a cryptographic key in a secure way?

Comment: If the transmitter only uses S1, what is the role of S2 on reception?

Answer (score 1):

I understand the OP is describing encoding each bit in the key with repeated use of orthogonal waveforms (spread spectrum). No it wouldn't be secure. The known waveforms are then a "key to get the key" and sent repeatably in the clear. If we are matched filtering to the reception to determine each symbol (as spread-spectrum), then this means we are receiving that "key to get the key" and anyone else can receive it as well. To get a sufficiently high SNR copy, we can either move closer to the transmitter or point a very high gain antenna at it.

Further we can detect it's presence and timing by auto-correlating the sequence to itself.

This would be in contrast to using a private set of orthogonal waveforms each of which is used once and never repeated, and the transmitter and receiver have time synchronization and knowledge as to which code is transmitted when (or approximately when such that synchronization can be refined through code correlation).